# collaborative filtering library in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

does any of you know any good specific library that contains implementations of common algorithms specifically geared towards collaborative filtering/recommendation system that is written in C++

so just like a machine learning library except that it's specifically geared towards collaborative filtering and/or recommendation system

Comment: If you haven't already, you might like to read http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/collabnetwork.aspx.  Sorry - not aware of anything else relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some time ago on Google Code (I haven't used them yet):

http://code.google.com/p/recsys-nju/
http://code.google.com/p/recsyscode/

http://code.google.com/p/recsysexperiment/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at GraphLab, SVDFeature, or Waffles, which are all written in C++ and open source/free software. There is also LibFM, which is available for free as in beer, but free as in freedom ...

- http://graphlab.org/pmf.html
- http://apex.sjtu.edu.cn/apex_wiki/svdfeature

I do not know about Waffles, but the other 3 are capable of handling very large datasets.

PS: StackOverflow did not allow me to post more than two URLs, but I guess you can use Google to find the other two packages ...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [LensKit](http://lenskit.grouplens.org/). It's actually a Java library, but I'm bringing it up because they are also working on incorporating stuff from [GraphLab](http://graphlab.org) (a C++ library) into it.

Here is a [post by Danny Bickson](http://bickson.blogspot.com/2011/12/spotlight-michael-ekstrand-and-lenskit.html), one of the lead developers of GraphLab, interviewing one of the PhD students working on LensKit.

Answer (score 1):

GraphChi http://graphchi.org contains also high-performance collaborative filtering toolkit written by Danny Bickson: http://bickson.blogspot.com/2012/08/collaborative-filtering-with-graphchi.html